# Laravel 5.1 - mass-assignable field, only when creating

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-5, mass-assignment

I have a model containing some $fillable, mass-assignable fields.

However, some of the fields should only be mass-assignable when creating, not when updating.

What is the correct method of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you could try overriding `getFillable` on the model.

```php
public function getFillable()
{
    if ($this->exists) {
        // modify the fillable or return a different fillable array
    }

    return $this->fillable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking of this - but is it the right way? It feels a bit dodgy overriding stuff, instead of defining the situational fillables to start with. (If that's even possible).

Comment: I was also thinking about just making an impossible validation rule for the exception fields, that would work, be easy to do, but feels dodgy as well.

Comment: there might be other places you could override or in a different way. with this approach you could define a second fillable array and return that, which would make it conditional.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to overload getFillable()

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent
{
    public function create(array $attributes = []) {
        $this->fill($attributes);
        $this->protected_attriute = $attribute['protected_attribute'];

        return $this;
    }
}
```